# Page not working in iFrame on IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, conditional-statements

I have a page that works propper in all browsers, also in IE, but when I load it in iFrame it seems, that my javascript does not work. I used selectivzr to make  css3 selectors work in IE.
Is it possible, that some conditional comments or browser detection scripts does not work in iFrame in IE?
I have no idea how to find the error...

Update: I found out that some javascript in the parent page is broken, which actually should not harm the js in my iFrame or does it have any influence?

The problem occurs in IE 7 & 8, IE does not need the selectivzr JS fallback. So I'm pretty sure, that somehow this script is not working propper. What it should do is styling checkboxes using css3, pretty the same like here: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-checkbox-styles

Comment: that's what I thought before too ... but maybe some things behaving strange in iFrame, I found this so far: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/85cfa7aa-522b-4ac8-8ccf-06655a26130c/

Comment: Did you add DOCTYPE ? <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">

Comment: I'm using this: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: Try and be more specific; post some code, tell us which version of ie please. I'm not sure if this applies here but I remember reading something about the "Same Origin Policy", which may apply here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: I made an update. Sorry for not posting code, but I don't know which part could be relevant and it's really a lot of code.